# How to make an ER Digram show joins

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, entity-relationship

Let’s say I have two tables table 1 has columns name, date of birth, zip code, "random stuff"

Table 2 has 3 columns.  Income, "random stuff", education.

If we just do an inner join we would could do

```
Select *
From table 1
Join Table 2
USING (random stuff)
```

and we are all happy right?

Okay, how do I show this on an ER diagram. And when I say this, I do not mean how do I make a table 1 and table 2 on an ER diagram.
How can I make table 3 on an ER diagram showing that we used "random stuff" to join Table 1 and Table 2?

Or is this not what an ER diagram is used for?

Also random stuff is not a primary key since there can be multiple exact values of this in each table the other 2 columns are different in each table are usually difference hence why its not usually just duplicate rows with no new info.

Comment: Or is this not what an ER diagram is used for? - Correct,  ER diagrams are for showing relationships (by FK)

Comment: The ERD is to show related entity, in your case between table there is no relation at all which is the FK in one of them.